# how to understand 'end to end' in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Recently, I do some literature research about CNN and find there is a concept of

> end to end training

Such as the abstract in [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)

How to understand that? What is end-to-end training?

Comment: I understand now. It means that during training, the algorithm does not have  **separate procedures**, just have one step.

Comment: +1 for linking to a great paper :-)

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, we extract pre-defined features before prediction.

> data -> extracted features -> learning algorithm -> output

However, hand-engineered features limit the potential performance as some of them are poor approximation of reality and some of them throw away some information.

End-to-end learning means that we **replace the pipeline with a single learning algorithm** so that it goes directly from the input to the desired output to overcome limitations of the traditional approach.

> data -> learning algorithm -> output

End-to-end learning system tend to do better when there is a lot of labeled data as the learning algorithm can somehow learn features by itself. When the training set is small, it tends to do worse than hand-engineered pipeline.